# value returns 0 or undefined on MUI autocomplete unable to fetch the value in multiple attribute

Tags: reactjs, arrays, material-ui, autocomplete, user-defined-functions

On MUI Autocomplete component where the attribute is multiple, then the value prop returns 0 or undefined when we choose anyone of the selected option.

```
<Autocomplete
  value={v.education}
  onChange={handleEducationChange}
  className={classes.textOutline}
  multiple
  id="virtualize-demo"
  name="education"
  style={{ width: 600 }}
  disableCloseOnSelect
  ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
  options={educationList()}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
  isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
    option.title === value.title
  }
  renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
    <li {...props}>
      <Checkbox
        icon={icon}
        checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
        style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
        checked={selected}
      />
      {option.title}
    </li>
  )}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      variant="outlined"
      name="education"
      placeholder="Select your Qualification"
      label="Education"
      fullWidth
    />
  )}
/>
```

```
  // handleEducationChange
  const initialState = { education: "", occupation: "" };

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState([], initialState);

  const handleEducationChange = (event) => {
    const { name, values } = event.target;

    setSelectedOption({ ...selectedOption, [name]: values });

    console.log(values);
  };
```

I need the selected value to be passed with value prop and that can be validated and posted to backend... kindly update the solution for this, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must change `values` to `value` and delete the array from `useState`:

```
   // handleEducationChange
  const initialState = { education: "", occupation: "" };

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(initialState);

  const handleEducationChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setSelectedOption({ ...selectedOption, [name]: value });

    console.log(value);
  };
```